# Multidimensional array and nested loop in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to show number using decrement array but I got problems: the loop doesn't stop.

Input sample:

```
5
5
```

Output:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

I used 2d array, but I know my problem is in my logic program. Maybe someone wants to help me to fix this program?

My program :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main(){
    
    int row, column, i, j;
    cout<<"masukkan baris: "<<endl;
    cin>>row;
    cout<<"masukkan column: "<<endl;
    cin>>kolom;
    
    int array[row][column];

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j--) {
            cout <<array[i][j]++<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you get on the sample input? Why have you come to conclusion that the program has a logic problem? Please explain.

Comment: i dont know how to used array if it content doesn't input cause the input requested it's only for size of array

Comment: You don't need an array for that task.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think second loop's index (`j--`) has the problem.

It solve only infinite loop.

I change single-line only to start programming.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main(){
    
    int row, column, i, j;
    cout<<"masukkan baris: "<<endl;
    cin>>row;
    cout<<"masukkan column: "<<endl;
    cin>>kolom;
    
    int array[row][column]; // initialize

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        //for (j = 0; j < column; j--) {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            cout <<array[i][j]++<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

ps) I think `array` is unsafe to use for value's name.